# replace a word with " (double quote) using replace function in shell script (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, shell, replace

I am trying this:-
replace(replace(colname,'AND',','),'OR','"')

colname -

OR SUBMITTED STATE OR AND OR NOT HEALTHY OR AND OR HELLO WORLD OR
"Submitted State","Not Healthy","Hello World"

Comment: your question is not clear enough, also fix your code format! specify exactly what you want to do and what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
select initcap(
        regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
          regexp_replace(
           'OR SUBMITTED STATE OR AND OR NOT HEALTHY OR AND OR HELLO WORLD OR',
           '\yOR\y', '"', 'g'
          ), 
          '\yAND\y', ',', 'g'
         ), 
         ' *([,"]) *', '\1', 'g'
        )
       );

                    initcap                    
-----------------------------------------------
 "Submitted State","Not Healthy","Hello World"
(1 row)
```